# Azure Key Vault - is there a .NET Core API for that?

Tags: c#, security, .net-core, azure-keyvault

I'm looking for a simple class allowing to access the Azure Key Vault secrets in my .NET Core app run on Ubuntu server. I don't want to use Powershell, I don't want to spend too much time for the configuration.

There is a REST API. I can write a wrapper over it, but I suspect the wrapper should already exist in the .NET Core framework, I just can't find it.

So, is there a .NET Core wrapper over Azure Key Vault REST API with some documentation and examples?

It is also important I need to use it without ASP.NET. Just plain .NET Core console application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using these NuGet packages any application access AKV if you just provide the correct credentials.

```
  <PackageReference Include="Azure.Security.KeyVault.Certificates" Version="4.1.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Azure.Security.KeyVault.Keys" Version="4.1.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets" Version="4.1.0" />
```

Then you can pretty easily, create a client instance, like this:

```
var credentials = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId: tenantId, clientId: clientId, clientSecret: secret);
var certClient = new CertificateClient(new Uri(vaultUrl), credentials);
var secretClient = new SecretClient(new Uri(vaultUrl), credentials);
```

Then you do your operations against AKV.

Comment: Hm, it tries to work, however I get 403, that my app does not have permissions. It does. I set access policies, I registered application. Everything is set, but all I get is 403.

Comment: Getting the access can be tricky to get right. The app also needs to have proper access to AKV , including the GET and LIST operations.

Comment: I got it. You don't specify the application in application field, but in the principal field ;) Azure panel is weird. It works now, however, one problem remains - how to store the secret key to the vault ;) I guess - in a file kept separate from the source, right?

Comment: Where do you deploy your app?

Comment: Ubuntu VM on Azure. I test in on my Windows machine, then I just upload it to my Linux server.

Comment: I guess in the enviroment variables or a local file will work... I usually deploy my app to Azure Container Instances and host the login credentials inside ACI.